# How is this load able to perform any useful work other than heating?

Tags: circuit-analysis, load

Consider a voltage source with some internal resistance, in series with a load. It turns out that the voltage source produces a power equal to \$I^2R_\text{total}\$ (this can be seen by using P=IV and Ohm's law). So far so good.

However this power is also equal to the power dissipated in the whole circuit (I guess this is wrong but I don't see how). Indeed, the power source dissipates \$I^2R_\text{source}\$ while the load dissipates \$I^2R_\text{load}\$ because its impedance is \$R_\text{load}\$. This means there is no energy left for the load to do anything, as \$ R_\text{total}=R_\text{source}+R_\text{load}\$. Obviously this cannot be correct. For example it should be possible to charge up a capacitor if the load was a complicated circuit containing a capacitor. But from the above reasoning, there is no more energy than the one used as Joule heat both in the voltage source and in the load itself.

Can someone point me where the reasoning is wrong and why it is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> Consider a voltage source with some internal resistance, in series with a load. **It turns out that the voltage source produces a power equal to \$I^2R_\text{total}\$** (this can be seen by using P=IV and Ohm's law).

This first assumption is incorrect. This is only true for **resistive** loads.
When you add reactance (inductive or capacitive), there will be [reactive power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power) which is not dissipated / become Joule heat.

Comment: I see, this is the most informative answer so far. Does this mean that commercial DC-DC converters which use a MPPT DO NOT actually adjust the impedance to that of the power source. Rather they adjust it to some complex number value in order to allow reactive power?

Comment: I am now reading on Wikipedia that this reactive power can do no work, i.e. the load cannot perform any useful work with it even though the source has to spend such an amount of power. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power#Active,_reactive,_and_apparent_power

Answer (score 2):

Not completely clear what you mean when you say 'no energy left for load to do anything'. When your load consumes a power equivalent to I^2*R, it has all the liberty to do anything with this energy. If it was a resistor it would plainly convert this energy to heat. If it was a bulb, it would convert some energy to light and some to heat. Even non static loads can be modelled using an effective resistance and these loads use the overall power budget they get to convert into various forms of energy.

So when it is said that a load would consume power equivalent to I^2*R, it simply means this much energy will be consumed and converted to other forms of energy, now it depends on the load on whether it dissipates this energy as heat or mechanical movements or light.

Hope this clarifies your confusion.

Comment: Not really, this is what I suspected, but I still do not understand why the load would not have a Joule heat equal to \$I^2R_\text{load}\$.

Comment: I^2 * R is a formula for power consumed inside a device which can be modelled using an effective resistance. Nowhere in electronics you would find that this power must be lost as heat. How the power is lost completely depends on the load. Theoretically if the load was an ideal motor or some other device, it would convert 100% of that power to other forms and zero power converted into joules lost as heat.

Comment: I have done the math assuming a 100% reactive (0% dissipative) load and this is not what I found. I found that the produced power is lesser than if the load was purely resistive. More precisely, I find that the power produced is \$I^2(\sqrt 2-1)R_\text{source}\$ in impedance matching. I trust your comment and that I made a mistake, but since I cannot spot any mistake in my calculations, so far your comment lacks weight and should be backed up by a calculation in your answer to demonstrate that you're correct. :)

Comment: Furthermore, according to wikipedia the load cannot perform any useful work with reactive power: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power#Active,_reactive,_and_apparent_power.

Answer (score 1):

That real power may become heat, sound, light, or any other form of energy...it doesn't necessarily all become heat.  In the case of a capacitive load, energy is stored and sometimes returned to the source.  It may also be dissipated elsewhere in the circuit.  There will always be some heat, but efficiency varies.  Of course if your load is a heating coil, the heat is kind of the point of it.

Remember to distinguish between resistance and impedance--resistance has a real value, while impedance may have both real and imaginary (reactive) components.  Resistance dissipates power, where reactive impedance stores power.

Comment: This is what I suspected, but I don't see it. This would mean the load does NOT have a Joule heat of \$ I^2 R_\text{load}\$. How is that possible?

Comment: Because \$R_\text{load}\$, in the case of a capacitive load, is zero (for an ideal cap).  \$Z_\text{load}\$ can be calculated, but it will be imaginary, and only real impedances dissipate heat.

Comment: Could you please add this information in your answer? This is precisely what I overlooked.

Comment: Hmm but this still doesn't make it. According to Wikipedia the reactive power can do no useful work, i.e. the load cannot convert that power into anything useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power#Active,_reactive,_and_apparent_power. So I am still entirely left blank.

Comment: That's entirely true, reactive power is not real power...it's imaginary both mathematically and practically.  If you plot the instantaneous power--current times voltage--in a reactive load, you'll see that it changes signs during the cycle indicating that the load is receiving power at some times and sourcing it at others.  In other words, it's temporarily stored and then returned to the source.  If the source has a real source impedance, the source will dissipate power, but a completely reactive load just passes it back and forth.

Comment: I see... so a purely reactive load couldn't even store energy into a capacitor which would later be used as a power source to power anything?

Comment: A capacitor is a reactive load, and is perfectly capable of storing energy.  If the source is AC, the capacitor is alternately storing energy from the source during parts of the cycle and sending it back during the other parts.  If you were to remove it when it is charged, it would contain some energy that can be used as a power source.  This would, of course, be easier if the source is DC.

Comment: Alright, I'm confused then. If the source is DC and the capacitor is able to store usable energy this would mean that a purely reactive load is able to store useful energy, which I thought was not possible?

Comment: No, a purely reactive load doesn't DISSIPATE energy.  Whatever energy you put into it is available to take out.  Sometimes it goes back to the source, sometimes it goes somewhere else.  A purely resistive load can dissipate energy, but it can't store it.